# How to request Place Details from Google Places API using place_id in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, request, google-places-api

Im creating an app that needs to be able to determine what locations are in a given area and then retrieve details about those locations, which then will be displayed. To do this I've been using Google Places API, but I am having trouble retrieving place details for locations using their place_id.

At the moment I am able to successfully perform a Google Places 'Nearby Search' request which returns many locations and some basic data about them (including a place_id). What I'm having trouble with is using the place-id's I receive from the first request to make a 'Place Details' request to get all the information Google has about the respective location.

vv My code below details my current attempt vv

function where I call the 2 requests:

```
    func requestAndCombineGData(location: CLLocation, radius: Int) {

        self.mapView.clear()

        // Calls 'Nearby Search' request
        googleClient.getGooglePlacesData(location: location, withinMeters: radius) { (response) in
            print("Made Nearby Search request. Passed response here:", response)

            // loops through each result from the 'Nearby Request' to get the 'place_id' and make 'Place Details'
            for location in response.results {
                // Calls 'Place Details' request
                self.googleClient.getGooglePlacesDetailsData(place_id: location.place_id) { (detailsResponse) in
                    print("Made Place Details request. Passed response here:", detailsResponse)

//                    function to drop markers using data received above here
//                    self.putPlaces(places: response.results)
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**GoogleClient.swift** file that contains the code for handling the requests above:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


//Protocol
protocol GoogleClientRequest {
    var googlePlacesKey : String { get set }
    func getGooglePlacesData(location: CLLocation, withinMeters radius: Int, using completionHandler: @escaping (GooglePlacesResponse) -> ())
    func getGooglePlacesDetailsData(place_id: String, using completionHandler: @escaping (GooglePlacesDetailsResponse) -> ())
}



// GoogleClient class that conforms to the ZGoogleClient Request protocol
class GoogleClient: GoogleClientRequest {

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var googlePlacesKey: String = "MY_KEY_GOES_HERE"
    let categoriesArray = [
        "park",
        "restaurant",
        "zoo"
    ]


    func getGooglePlacesData(location: CLLocation, withinMeters radius: Int, using completionHandler: @escaping (GooglePlacesResponse) -> ())  {

        for category in categoriesArray {

            let url = googlePlacesNearbyDataURL(forKey: googlePlacesKey, location: location, radius: radius, type: category)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (responseData, _, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = responseData, let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GooglePlacesResponse.self, from: data) else {
                    print("Could not decode JSON response")
                    completionHandler(GooglePlacesResponse(results:[]))
                    return
                }


                if response.results.isEmpty {
                    print("GC - response returned empty", response)
                } else {
                    print("GC - response contained content", response)
                    completionHandler(response)
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }

    }


    func getGooglePlacesDetailsData(place_id: String, using completionHandler: @escaping (GooglePlacesDetailsResponse) -> ())  {

        let url = googlePlacesDetailsURL(forKey: googlePlacesKey, place_ID: place_id)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (responseData, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let data = responseData, let detailsResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GooglePlacesDetailsResponse.self, from: data) else {
                print("Could not decode JSON response. responseData was: ", responseData)
                completionHandler(GooglePlacesDetailsResponse(results:[]))
                return
            }

//                print("response result: ", detailsResponse.results)

            if detailsResponse.results.isEmpty {
                print("getGPDetails - response returned empty", detailsResponse)
            } else {
                print("getGPDetails - response contained content", detailsResponse)
                completionHandler(detailsResponse)
            }

        }
        task.resume()

    }


    func googlePlacesNearbyDataURL(forKey apiKey: String, location: CLLocation, radius: Int, type: String) -> URL {
        print("passed  location  before url creation ", location)
        print("passed  radius  before url creation ", radius)

        let baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
        let locationString = "location=" + String(location.coordinate.latitude) + "," + String(location.coordinate.longitude)
        let radiusString = "radius=" + String(radius)
        let typeString = "type=" + String(type)
//        let rankby = "rankby=distance"
//        let keywrd = "keyword=" + keyword
        let key = "key=" + apiKey

        print("Request URL:", URL(string: baseURL + locationString + "&" + radiusString + "&" + type + "&" + key)!)
        return URL(string: baseURL + locationString + "&" + radiusString + "&" + typeString + "&" + key)!
    }


    func googlePlacesDetailsURL(forKey apiKey: String, place_ID: String) -> URL {
        print("passed  place_ID  before url creation ", place_ID)

        let baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
        let place_idString = "place_id=" + place_ID
        let fields = "fields=rating"
        let key = "key=" + apiKey

        print("Details request URL:", URL(string: baseURL + place_idString + "&" + fields + "&" + key)!)
        return URL(string: baseURL + place_idString + "&" + fields + "&" + key)!
    }



}
```

**ResponseModels.swift** file that holds the structs to handle the 2 different request responses:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation



struct GooglePlacesResponse : Codable {
    let results : [Place]
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case results = "results"
    }
}



// Place struct
struct Place : Codable {

    let geometry : Location
    let name : String
    let place_id: String
    let openingHours : OpenNow?
    let photos : [PhotoInfo]?
    let types : [String]
    let address : String


    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case geometry = "geometry"
        case name = "name"
        case place_id = "place_id"
        case openingHours = "opening_hours"
        case photos = "photos"
        case types = "types"
        case address = "vicinity"
    }


    // Location struct
    struct Location : Codable {

        let location : LatLong

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case location = "location"
        }


        // LatLong struct
        struct LatLong : Codable {

            let latitude : Double
            let longitude : Double

            enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
                case latitude = "lat"
                case longitude = "lng"
            }
        }

    }


    // OpenNow struct
    struct OpenNow : Codable {

        let isOpen : Bool

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case isOpen = "open_now"
        }
    }


    // PhotoInfo struct
    struct PhotoInfo : Codable {

        let height : Int
        let width : Int
        let photoReference : String

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case height = "height"
            case width = "width"
            case photoReference = "photo_reference"
        }
    }



}



struct GooglePlacesDetailsResponse : Codable {
    let results : [PlaceDetails]
    enum CodingKeysDetails : String, CodingKey {
        case results = "results"
    }
}



// PlaceDetails struct
// I have fields commented out because I wanted to just get a location's rating for testing before implementing the rest
struct PlaceDetails : Codable {

//    let place_id: String
//    let geometry : Location
//    let name : String
    let rating : CGFloat?
//    let price_level : Int
//    let types : [String]
//    let openingHours : OpenNow?
//    let formatted_address : String
//    let formatted_phone_number : String
//    let website : String
//    let reviews : String
//    let photos : [PhotoInfo]?


    enum CodingKeysDetails : String, CodingKey {
//        case place_id = "place_id"
//        case geometry = "geometry"
//        case name = "name"
        case rating = "rating"
//        case price_level = "price_level"
//        case types = "types"
//        case openingHours = "opening_hours"
//        case formatted_address = "formatted_address"
//        case formatted_phone_number = "formatted_phone_number"
//        case website = "website"
//        case reviews = "reviews"
//        case photos = "photos"
    }



}
```

Google Places API documentation I've been referencing:

```
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
```

-

Like I said above, right now my first request ('Nearby Search') is successfully returning data, but when I try to implement the second request ('Place Details') using a 'place_id'. My console keeps returning "Could not decode JSON response. Response:  Optional(106 bytes)" which comes from a comment in my 'GoogleClient.swift' file.

My questions are:

**What is wrong with how I'm making the 'Place Details' request that is causing it to return that the response cant be decoded?**

AND

**Is there a better way to make a Nearby Search request then use the 'place_id' from the returned locations to make a Place Details request in swift?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're having is with your model:

```
struct GooglePlacesDetailsResponse : Codable {
let results : [PlaceDetails]
enum CodingKeysDetails : String, CodingKey {
    case results = "results"
}
```

}

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) there is no key on the place details response for "results" the correct key is "result" non-plural. Also you define the model as an array of the struct PlaceDetails, which is incorrect. When you return place details using a place id it will return only one object, which is the place details for that specific id as the place id is a unique value. I expect if you correct your response model your issues should resolve.

Comment: Youre right, it's working now! Thank you.   Do you happen to know if this is the best way to be making multiple requests in succession to google?

Comment: Glad it works! Unfortunately if you want the place details response you do have to iterate over each id and make the requests separately. However one thing to consider in improving your app, might be to hold off making the place details request until the user actually needs that data (like if you're displaying the data when they click on a location). Otherwise if you are displaying all of the place details data for a group of locations at the same time you could grab one at a time so that you can display the data as it's returned rather than wait for all of it.